# Can light affect specific objects only?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

In C4D I can control which objects to affect with a light, in the image below only the main object is affected by the light source, the background and other objects are not affected. But I haven't found a way to do this in blender!

Is it possible to specify which objects to affect with a light source?

[image: pic]

Comment: If your question is: can light only affect some objects and not others? I think it's not possible yet

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to understand, feel free to [edit] or roll back if it's not what you wanted to ask.

Comment: If you don't mind using OSL, you can light selectively [this way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116007/35559), but I think you would want to check that render passes wasn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To remove specular, as that's the name for the thing pointed to, you select the faces that shouldn't have it and give them material of the same color, but with a **different name**. Then, in a node, set its Roughness to 1. This goes for Cycles.