# Object should not be affected by one light source

Tags: light

I want it, so my object is affected by light but not by the light from one light source.

Comment: for the moment I think you need to do it through the compositor

Comment: @moonboots so there is no solution for this? If no how should I do it then in the compositor? Im not that familiar with it...

Comment: you need to put your object in a collection, create 2 View Layers, each one with the collections you want to enable, then mix them with a Alpha Over node in the Compositor, but there must already be a detailed answer on this matter somewhere

Comment: ??? ... happy that moonboots understood your question.

Comment: @vklidu I have multiple light sources in my scene. I have one object I want to be affected by all the lights except one. Do you understand it now? Eventually you can help me too :)

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! If there is no other option I'll definety try this.

Comment: Than moonboots is right ... or @RobinBetts answer seems to be for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116007/2214 (OSL shader = CPU only) ... btw can you add screen of real situation this can be useful?

Comment: in Eevee you can try a trick like light with negative strength value but as Vklidu says it depends on your scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@RobinBetts script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116007/2214) for OSL shader (CPU only) ...

- second *Mix Shader* socket leave empty and
- for an object you want to exclude from lightning set under
  *Object Properties > Relations > Pass Index* <kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to the question. It works now!