# Is there a way to limit the distance travelled by an emission ray?

Tags: shaders

I want to make an object that's emission strength can be increased as much as I want but the the light should only affect objects within a certain distance and not beyond that. Is it possible to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with the Light path node, using the Ray length option in a first approach.

If a more precise result is needed by ignoring completely the light source for certain objects, an OSL solution has been proposed here:
[Is it possible to have an object ignore a certain light source but still be affected by others?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115967/is-it-possible-to-have-an-object-ignore-a-certain-light-source-but-still-be-affe)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you !!! Hero of the day!